# android translate animation clips the part of view not shown on screen

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a Relative Layout containing some textviews which floats over a gridview. When I select an item in the grid, the layout moves down to nearly the end of the screen and only about 1/5th of it is visible. This is done using simple Translate Animation. Now when I click another button in the grid, I need to Relative Layout to move back to its original position on top of the gridview. I did this also with Translate Animation and this is happnening, but only the portion of the RelativeLayout which was visible when it was collapsed is translating (moving) and the other portion becomes visible after animation has ended. This looks really ugly.

I know that Android doesnt draw the portion of the view that is not visible on the screen. Is there a way to force draw the full portion ?

My Animation code is given below:

```
  public void smoothExpanderAnimate(final int finalTarget,final RelativeLayout expander,final int animateToY,final boolean setExpanded,final boolean refreshGrid)
{
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams head_params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)expander.getLayoutParams();
    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, 0f, animateToY);
    anim.setDuration(400);

    //timeListHeight = list.getHeight();
    //anim.setFillAfter(true);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            //Should I try something here ?

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            head_params.topMargin = finalTarget;
            expander.clearAnimation();
            expander.setLayoutParams(head_params);

            isExpanded = setExpanded;
            isAnimating = false;



            if(!setExpanded)
            {
                setChildHeight(timeListHeight, list);
            }
        }
    });



    isAnimating = true;
    expander.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this.

If you dont need to support lower API levels and are fine with API level 11 onwards, you can use ObjectAnimator for this. ObjectAnimator has a translatey method which works quite well.

If you need to support API 8 onwards, you need to make sure your view comes within the bounds of the screen and then animates. The following code modification did the trick.

I know it seems very weird, do let me know if there is a better way to do this.

```
 public void smoothExpanderAnimate(boolean addSpecialFix,final int finalTarget,final RelativeLayout expander,final int animateToY,final boolean setExpanded,final boolean refreshGrid)
{
    final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams head_params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)expander.getLayoutParams();
    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, 0f, animateToY);
    anim.setDuration(400);
    expander.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //Make View invisible

    if(isExpanded && addSpecialFix){  

    //THIS IS THE FIX

        int old = head_params.topMargin;
        head_params.topMargin = finalTarget;
        expander.clearAnimation();
        expander.setLayoutParams(head_params); //move invisible view to the final position
    anim = new TranslateAnimation(0f, 0f, old-closedY, 0);
    Log.d("asdasd", old+"");
    anim.setDuration(400);


    }
    //timeListHeight = list.getHeight();
    //anim.setFillAfter(true);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            head_params.topMargin = finalTarget;
            expander.clearAnimation();
            expander.setLayoutParams(head_params);

            isExpanded = setExpanded;
            isAnimating = false;
            expander.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(refreshGrid)
            {
                mCalAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            if(!setExpanded)
            {
                setListHeight(timeListHeight, list);
            }
        }
    });



    isAnimating = true;
    expander.startAnimation(anim);
}
```